# Shading language version:1.30 (off) in virtual nano lab running on ubuntu

Tags: drivers, opengl

I am currently using virtual nano lab for scientific purposes. It contains a option called builder where we can build atomic structures and proceed for further process, but in my case, it is not seen at all and the builder screen is blank while other options are visible. I checked the graphic libraries and when I saw shading language version of openGL is off. i donot know how to turn it on. With out this, I cannot build atomic structures. Please help me in this regard.

```
Virtual NanoLab - Atomistix ToolKit - Version 2017.0
======================================================
System information
===================
Build: 2017.0.15d690e
Platform: Linux
Python 2.7.11
Qt 5.5.0
PyQt 4.11.4

OpenGL information
===================
Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center
Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Broadwell 
Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
Shading language version: **1.30 (off)**
```